# Model doesn't appear to be inheriting

Tags: python, django, model

I am attempting to have one class relate to another in my models.py but it seems that only my Card class is relating to Subject correctly. I am trying to have them relate like so: "Each Stack will have multiple Subject(s), and each category will have multiple Card(s). When I run my migration I have no errors, but it only says:

```
Migrations for 'flashcards':
flashcards/migrations/0001_initial.py
- Create model Card
- Create model Stack
- Create model Subject
- Add field subject to card
```

Just based on my migrations output it seems that only Card was related to Subject but Subject was not related to Stack, or am I reading this wrong and it worked fine? I am a new programmer, and only just learning how to test.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Stack(models.Model): #A stack of cards that contains multiple 
categories
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Subject(models.Model): #Subjects that are related to each stack
title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) #Title of the Category (ie: 
Spanish)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True) 
#Category Description
stack = models.ForeignKey(Stack, on_delete = models.CASCADE)


class Card(models.Model): #cards that are related to each subject
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
key = models.CharField(max_length = 300) #Card Question
answer = models.CharField(max_length = 300) # Card Answer
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong here. The migration log output doesn't indicate anything wrong in this context. The reason the `subject` was added to `Card` in a separate line is because Django first had to create the `Subject` model. It didn't need to split the steps when creating the `Subject` though.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have slightly misinterpreted the output you get from running `makemigrations`, everything is working as expected here.

I created a test project using the code you provided and ran `makemigrations` on the `flashcards` app. Looking at the contents of the migration file `0001_initial.py` that was generated:

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.7 on 2019-03-30 03:20

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(  # Summarised as: - Create model Card
            name='Card',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('key', models.CharField(max_length=300)),
                ('answer', models.CharField(max_length=300)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(  # Summarised as: - Create model Stack
            name='Stack',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)),
                ('description', models.CharField(max_length=300)),
                ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('published_date', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(  # Summarised as: - Create model Subject
            name='Subject',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('description', models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)),

                # As the ``Stack`` model has been created it can include the ForeignKey definition here.
                ('stack', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='flashcards.Stack')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(  # Summarised as: - Add field subject to card
            model_name='card',
            name='subject',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='flashcards.Subject'),
        ),
    ]
```

The output you see after you run `makemigrations` is a brief summary of the migration file that was generated.

Due to the order Django is creating the models it can't add the `subject` field to `Card` because `Subject` hasn't been created yet. So it skips the `subject` field and adds it after the `Subject` model has been created.

I can understand why this looked a little confusing, the reason there is no explicit message saying something like `- Add field stack to subject` is because the `stack` field is added in the `- Create model Subject` step.

Comment: Awesome thank you tons for your time Jamie, I'm coming from a small amount of Ruby on Rails background where database management was much easier when it came to relationships. It's also nice to know where I can find the migration file as well. Quite the learning curve!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. I've never used Ruby on Rails so I can't really say much on that one. Another quick point I forgot to add to my answer; you can use strings in the ForeignKey field definitions like so `stack = models.ForeignKey('flashcards.Stack', ...)`, this will let you define the models in any order you wish and also, when using models from other apps you won't need to import them.